# how to auto generate voucher code on submit button click

Tags: c#, asp.net

Here is basically what i want to do:

i have a web form in asp.net that has a first name and last name and a submit button,

now on submit button click, i would like to display an auto generated voucher code!

how should i go abut it?

this is what i have in my .cs file:

```
 namespace WebApplication1
{
    public partial class DetailsForm : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }``

        [WebMethod]
        public static string InsertMethod(string firstname, string lastname)
        {
            SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=KIMBERLY\SQLSERVER02;Initial Catalog=Chalegh;User ID=***;Password=***");
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("insert into TestTable values('"+ firstname +"','" + lastname +"')", con);
            con.Open();
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            return "True";
        }

        public static string GenerateVoucher(int length)
        {
            char[] CharArr = "0123456789ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ".ToCharArray();
            string randomString = string.Empty;
            Random objRandom = new Random();
            return randomString;


        }  
    }
}
```

Comment: Your code is affected to SQL injection. Never ever send string parameters as Query to SQL. You always need to send them by cmd.Parameters

Comment: Have you tried anything?  It looks like you already have a function to generate the code.  Is it not working in some way?  Have you tried calling that function and displaying the result on the page?

Comment: Should the voucher code be unique? Should it be calculated from the name? What exactly is your problem?

Comment: I think you've just posted your SQL username and password... on the public internet.

Comment: To sum up the SQL comments... You're doing *three* things wrong.  1) You're executing user input as code, also known as SQL injection.  User input should be values, *not* code.  2) You posted a password on the internet, probably not a good idea.  3) You're using the `sa` account for your application.  So not only can users arbitrarily execute code, they can execute it as the database's super user.  The application should have its own service account, it shouldn't be the database's super user.

Comment: @Jon Barker, don't worry it's just for development sake, im not planning on using those come deployment time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to do several things:

I will create a quick list, (I am assuming that you're using Visual Studio)

1) Create a button to `submit` button your changes (*Drag a button onto the webpage*)

2) Create an event handler for your button (*Double click on your button*)

3) Write the code for your handler

- Create an entry in the database
- Generate a voucher number
- Display it back to the screen

You're pretty close for your database portion, like the comments suggest you want to use parameters instead.

```
using (var con =new SqlConnection(yourConnectionString))
{
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("insert into TestTable values('@firstName', '@lastName')", con);
    SqlParameter paramFirstName= new SqlParameter();
    paramFirstName.ParameterName = "@firstName";
    paramFirstName.Value         = firstName;

    SqlParameter paramLastName= new SqlParameter();
    paramLastName.ParameterName = "@lastName";
    paramLastName.Value         = lastName;

    cmd.Parameters.Add(paramFirstName);
    cmd.Parameters.Add(paramLastName);
    con.Open();
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
```

For the generate the voucher number, I like Sudhakar Tillapudi's answer

```
String randomString = Guid.NewGuid().ToString("N").Substring(0, 6);
```

Then you need to display it to the screen.

- Create a label on your webform (EG: lblVoucherNumber)
- Assign the text value to the label

```
lblVoucherNumber.Text = randomString;
```

Please note that currently you aren't saving the voucher number. You'll likely want to save that voucher number somewhere (like in your TestTable, *please rename this when you put it into production*)

Comment: the code generated is actually way too long for what i actually want, is there a way to make the code let's say 6 digits?

Comment: What is unclear? I edited it to provide a 6 character (alpha/numeric) code, then in my comment, I pointed out exactly what I changed.

Comment: sorry, i missed the edited part! thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

you can use `GUID.NewGuid()` to get the unique ID values.

Try This:

```
String randomString = Guid.NewGuid().ToString("N");
```

**Suggestion 1:** your `INSERT INTO` statement is open to `sql injection attacks` so i would suggest you to use `Parameterised Queries` to avoid them.

**Suggestion 2:** you need to identify the execution status of the `ExecuteNonQuery()` method by checking its return value. `ExecuteNonQuery()` returns total number of rows updated in the database.

Try This:

```
 using(SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=KIMBERLY\SQLSERVER02;Initial     Catalog=Chalegh;User ID=***;Password=***"))
 {
   using(SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("insert into TestTable values(@firstname,@lastname)", con))
   {
     con.Open();
     int status = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
     if(status>0)
        return "True";

        return "False";
    }
  }
```

Comment: what if i want to make the generated code less longer? is there a way to do that?

Comment: @St3v3Al: currently i can not see any ways to reduce it as its already small peice of code , but what i suggest is `using{}` blocks will make your program more robust.

Comment: im actually talking about the voucher code generated by the Guid method! is there a way to make the voucher code shorter, lets say 6 characters long?